# Trying to get inner html of element by id

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get the inner html of an element on futbin as a learning challenge with the element being a players lowest by now. I can identify the element correctly but the inner html is returning null. The code is below as well as the html code on futbin i am using.

`<div id="xboxlowest" class="hide">52000</div>`

```
        final String playerPage = "https://www.futbin.com/21/player/583/alejandro-gomez";
        
        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(playerPage).get();
            Element price = document.getElementById("xboxlowest");
            System.out.println("Price: " + price.html());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The output i get from this function is

Price:

Im quite new to this web scraping so any ideas as to what im doing wrong but be really appreciated. Thanks for any replies

Comment: Ive just thought is it maybe because futbin probably update the html through code so maybe i cant read it?

Comment: That value is generated later dynamically (usually by JavaScript). `jsoup` is not browser emulator but HTML parser, so you would need to use other tools like Selenium webdriver which supports JS.